# Image Slider not showing till check with Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got a weird problem. By clicking on an image, I want to show a div with a bit of text a a image slider within.
Showing the box and the text is no problem, but the image slider stays empty TILL i check it with any dev tool.
I used 2 different slider plugins and programmed one by myself: same problem.
The wrapping div is set to "display: none", and is set to "display: block" when the user clicks on a specific item.

If you want to see by yourself, here's a link to the current project: 
http://keller.maxboettinger.de/?view=referenzen <- click on any gray image

Comment: It's not the console that triggers showing the image, it's that the console is triggering the `window.resize` event. It seems you're constantly calling bxslider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the plugin's issue, and has nothing to do with if you check it with the dev tool or not.
The image shows up when you resize the window.

If you look at the container with the class name "bx-viewport"

in container with id "referenzSlider"

you will see the height of "bx-viewport" is 0.

But if you resize the window, it sets to 186px